# How does Erlang list syntax [ a, b | [c, d] ] result in [ a, b, c, d]

Tags: erlang

I'm attempting to follow:
http://learnyousomeerlang.com/starting-out-for-real

There is a section demonstrating several equivalent list constructions:

> The ways Erlang lists can be built are sometimes
>   confusing to people who are not used to similar constructors. To help
>   you get familiar with the concept, read all of these examples (hint:
>   they're all equivalent):

```
[a, b, c, d]
[a, b, c, d | []]
[a, b | [c, d]] <---- I don't understand this one
[a, b | [c | [d]]]
[a | [b | [c | [d]]]]
[a | [b | [c | [d | [] ]]]]
```

The one I don't understand readily is:

```
[a, b | [c, d]]
```

I understand the normal nested constructor syntax, it just a recursively constructed list. But how does erlang handle this non nested term syntax? I would have expected evaluating `b | [c, d]` to result in `[b, c, d]` which would result in:

```
[a, [b , c, d]]
```

Sure, I could remember simply what the end result of the syntax is, but I'm looking for a more detailed explanation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The construct `| [c,d]` makes `[c,d]` the tail of the enclosing list. It doesn't matter how many elements like `a,b` are in the enclosing list ahead of the `|` separator since they are just normal elements of that enclosing list. In other words, the `|` separates list elements to its left from the list tail to its right.

Perhaps you're being confused by the construct `[Head|Tail]`, which is often used to process the head element of a list and then recursively process the tail. In this case, you can't extract the `b | [c,d]` portion of the syntax, treat it as equivalent to `[Head|Tail]` and then conclude an answer of `[a,[b,c,d]]` because `b` isn't the head of the list.

Comment: OK your first paragraph is a great way to remember.  I think the missing piece for me, which just clicked, is that `,` operator in the list is simply syntax sugar for `| [ ... ]`.  Is that correct?  I don't quite follow your second paragraph, but the syntax sugar explanation makes sense to me.

Comment: I suppose that's one way to look at it. A `,` indicates that what follows is another list element, while a `|` indicates that what follows is the list tail.

Comment: OH! I see, `|` is ALWAYS at the end which makes `[ a, b | [ c, d], e]` invalid.